# What to use to check multiple ifs for airport parking iprogram

Tags: c#

I want to make a program which plans park positions for incoming aircrafts at airport in C#. To do that, I need to consider aircrafts' type (big plane or small), domestic or international, terminal 1, or 2 or 3... etc. I can use many if statements such as:

---

```
if(aircraft is terminal 1){
   if(aircraft is domestic){
     if(aircraft is big){
       if(.....)
}else if(){
......
}
}else if(){.....}
}else if(){....}
```

---

But I don't see this way efficient. My question is that what can I use to check multiple conditions except using long sequences of ifs?
Or how should I approach this problem?
I would be very glad if you can give me any ideas about this.

Comment: I am not sure you are aware of it, but `is` is a C# keyword and it means a very specific thing.

Comment: Can you give more background of the problem? What are the main attributes? How are the properties stored? What decisions need to be taken? Which alternative approaches did you already try/think about?

Comment: Take a look at Constraint Solvers (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524509(v=vs.93).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to tell with so little information as you have given, but one approach would be the following:

Define a new class called `ParkingPosition` which contains requirements that an aircraft should meet in order to park there.

Create a list of instances of that class, with such requirements.

Then, once you have an aircraft that needs to park, loop through all available parking positions, and for each parking position:

- See if the aircraft matches the requirements of that parking position, and if so, park it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of 'gates' for your airport, which have the required properties, you could use LINQ to find what you want quickly.

For example, if you have a `Gate` which has the properties you need to check (like `SupportedSize`, `International`, and `TerminalNo`) and your aircraft had similar properties (`Size`, `International` and `Terminal`) then you could do something like this:

```
//(For this example you should have a class defined which has the properties of the parking positions, and one for the aircraft. Here I've used Gate and Plane respectively.)

//This is a list of the Gate object. Contains every gate and the properties about them.
var Gates = List<Gate>;
Plane aircraft;
//This will find spaces compatible with the supplied aircraft
IEnumerable<Gate> usableGates= Gates.Where(gate => gate.SupportedSize==aircraft.Size && gate.International==aircraft.International && gate.Terminal==aircraft.Terminal);
//Now any items which appear in usableGates should be usable for that aircraft
```

You can now iterate through `usableGates`, or just pick the first one, and 'park up' there.